# Gel redis keys (and theirs) with value more than a threshold

Tags: redis

I have a redis dump, which contains key/value pairs of type String/Double. Is it possible to get all the keys (or theirs counts), which have value more than a given number?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question

Comment: See if it is more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you use a SortedSet with your double as the score and your string as the member, and then you can [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore).

For example, to get all the members with a score greater than 1:

```
> ZADD zzz 1 one 2 two 3 three

(integer) 3

> ZRANGEBYSCORE zzz (1 +inf WITHSCORES

1) "two"
2) 2.0
3) "three"
4) 3.0
```